# Execute simple SQL query though Azure Devops CICD pipeline

Tags: azure, devops, cicd

I am new to Azure Devops and CICD pipeline. I have been tasked to create a CICD pipeline to execute a SQL query from Azure Devops CI/CD pipeline. How do I do that? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, when asking a question, please be sure to include what you have tried, and what errors you're running into. While @DreadedFrost was able to provide an answer, Stack Overflow is better suited for addressing specific technical questions, rather than general "getting started" types of questions.

Answer (score 1):

SQL queries can be ran via the [ADO tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Something like:

```
variables:
  AzureSubscription: '<Azure service connection>'
  ServerName: '<Database server name>'
  DatabaseName: '<Database name>'
  AdminUser: '<SQL user name>'
  AdminPassword: '<SQL user password>'
  SQLFile: '<Location of SQL file in $(Build.SourcesDirectory)>'

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@2
  displayName: Azure PowerShell script: FilePath
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
    ScriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\scripts\SetAzureFirewallRule.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '$(ServerName)'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion

- task: CmdLine@1
  displayName: Run Sqlcmd
  inputs:
    filename: Sqlcmd
    arguments: '-S $(ServerName) -U $(AdminUser) -P $(AdminPassword) -d $(DatabaseName) -i $(SQLFile)'

- task: AzurePowerShell@2
  displayName: Azure PowerShell script: FilePath
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
    ScriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\scripts\RemoveAzureFirewallRule.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '$(ServerName)'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

Note the extra steps is to remove the firewall if you are utilizing firewall rules

Comment: Used the AzurePowerShell@2 to execute the SQL query and it worked. Thank you for the info

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Windows agent you can run the [DacPac deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment-v1?view=azure-pipelines). The name is misleading; however, you can also run inline script or a script file.

```
    steps:
    - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
      inputs:
       azureSubscription: 'AzureSbxServiceConnection'
       AuthenticationType: 'servicePrincipal'
       ServerName: 'sql-bicepaad2-dev-eus.database.windows.net'
       DatabaseName: 'master'
       deployType: 'InlineSqlTask' 
       SqlInline: |
         IF NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT  [name]
 FROM    sys.database_principals
            WHERE   [name] = 'custom_user'
        )
        BEGIN
          CREATE USER [custom_user] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER WITH default_schema=[dbo]
          ALTER ROLE [sampleDB.db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [custom_user]
          ALTER ROLE [sampleDb.db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [custom_user]
          ALTER ROLE [sampleDB.db_ddladmin] ADD MEMBER [custom_user]
        END
        GO
```